# Confusing toggle button state.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, cookies

I am in the process of updating one of my form to jQuery toggle enabled. The form is huge and all fields aren't necessary but if a user wishes to fill all field it's even better. The general idea about having toggle is to hide all fields unnecessary so yeah the toggle.

While checking out a few example on the internet what I noticed that these form does not remember the state it was in once the user decide to close the window and come back later to fill it up, a browser cookie was must if I needed to have the "remember the state of the form".

```
<div class="onoffswitch">
    <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch"></label>
</div>
<p> hi </p>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/js-cookie/2.1.4/js.cookie.js"></script> 
<script>

$(function() {

  if (Cookies) {
    $("p").toggle(!(!!Cookies("toggle-state")) || Cookies("toggle-state") === 'true');
  }

  $('.onoffswitch-checkbox').click(function() {
     console.log($(this).is(":checked"));
      $("p").toggle();
      Cookies.set("toggle-state", $("p").is(':visible'), {
        expires: 1,
        path: '/'
      });
    });
});
```

And it's working, check [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d32j1tyt/2/).

What I noticed afterward is that now, the cookie remembers the toggle state in which it was last closed but not the toggle button state.

If I need to display the text, I switch the toggle button which slides to the left, turns green from grey and display the text. I close the form window, reload the same form the text is displayed (remember, we have a cookie and the last we closed the window was with text being displayed) but the toggle button is grey or off.

How to rectify this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your switch always starts out on because you have the checked attribute hard-coded into your HTML (or at least you do in your fiddle)

If you set the checked attribute with jQuery when you're doing the cookie check, it will work.

```
if (Cookies) {
    $("p").toggle(!(!!Cookies("toggle-state")) || Cookies("toggle-state") === 'true');

    // ADD THIS
    if(Cookies("toggle-state") === 'true') {
        $('#myonoffswitch').prop("checked", true);
    }
}
```